# Update Fragment after Async Task completes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a viewpager fragment setup, and I have an AsyncTask run at the start of the activity to load some data from a JSON get (the data it pulls only needs to be done once, and all fragments will use it). The problem I'm having is I want to take this data from the AsyncTask, and have it be the data that all of the textviews pull from in the fragments.

What would be the best way to load data from an AsyncTask and then have the fragments reference that data. You cant just have the views reference the data from the get-go as it Nullpointers, and I'd really like to avoid having to reference every single textview in the OnPostExecute of the AsyncTask if I had it in the Parent Activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just decouple the storage of the data from the view(s). In that way it will be easyer to handle the download of the data and to show it in the various fragments once the get is completed.

The basic idea is: launch the download in a background thread decoupled from the activity (service or intent service), then update the data a storage (sqllite if it is complex, shared preferences or even a singleton object, even though I don't like the latter approach).

Once the get is performed, inform the fragments that the data is available. Still, you have a lot of options here. If you decided to host the thread / asynctask inside a service, you can bind a callback to it and then notify all the fragments interested, you can use a (local) broadcast message that you can intercept using local broadcast receivers, or you can even use a message bus such as otto.

Finally, I really recommend to use an intent service to perform the async job. It's the easiest way to do any *one shot* operations without having to deal with service creation and/or with activity configuration changes.

Comment: The intent service was a good call, I like the way it was setup and fits what I want to do very well, and the broadcaster method for notifying the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the "best" way, but what comes to my mind first is the famous Observer pattern.

- Create an interface called `Observer` with a single method called
  notify()
- Implement this interface in all `Fragment`s that want to be notified when the data is ready
- Hold a `List` of `Observer` objects inside your `AsyncTask`
- In `onPostExecute()`, traverse this `List` and call notify() on every `Observer`, passing the appropriate data
- React on the notification inside your `Fragment`s given the data

This a very rough description of this solution, but I hope you get the idea.